# How to view days of Hystrix metrics in a dashboard for monitoring

Tags: dashboard, metrics, hystrix

Hystrix dashboard shows metrics only for a short period, say 10 secs. Is there a way I can store and see the metrics for the past week or so?

I came across some tools like Graphite, Servo, etc. But I couldn't understand how these tools could be integrated with hystrix stream. I'm looking for a **how to do answer** rather than a **what to use answer**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Boot then its pretty easy to send Hystrix metrics -> statsd -> Graphite. [Example export to statsd](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metric-writers-export-to-statsd).

Comment: Thanks for the info @Sneal. But I'm not working on a spring application and hence I don't use Spring boot. I need some guidance on how to do it in a simple java web application.